# Libreoffice base design of Time-Table for College

Tags: charts, libreoffice, database

I am supposed to work on THE Time-Table of my college which people have been doing manually so far. A college time-table is a mapping of a faculty to the class, day of the week, period of the day and the room number. It is published in three components, first, the faculty chart, second, the chart of a class that contains information of the room number and teacher's name for each period and third, the room chart that displays class and teacher's name for each period of each day of the week. In manual mode, a change made in one chart has to be incorporated in the other two simultaneously. I tried using Libreoffice base to make a database project that contains all the information of the time-table and reports the three charts.
My precise question is, can I design a user friendly interface that looks similar to the manual tables (images attached below) but takes care of the changes made in one chart and automatically (simultaneously) displays in the other t0o? Also, given the number of lectures of one faculty per week for a given class, can I automate the assignment of periods too?

FACULTY CHART:
[image: FACULTY CHART]

CLASS CHART:
[image: CLASS CHART]

ROOM CHART:
[image: ROOM CHART]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yea, I'm sure you can design such a UI. But this is too broad of a query for this site.

Comment: @music2myear I understand it. I have started learning Libreoffice base and I was wondering if this platform will be enough to cater to my needs or not. Maybe, as I shall proceed with my project, specific doubts and queries would appear.